# Pass elements between functions. Got negative result

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm working with hub-rest-functions: https://github.com/blackducksoftware/hub-rest-bash

I have an array of strings in my new "test.bash" script in the root folder:

```
get_groups=( "ABC MM CC IT Test RW" "ABC GG CMN IOSS Test RW" "ABC WW IMG IMGE Test RW" )
```

I need to get fourth element from each string and after that pass them to function "create_project()" from "project-functions.bash" :

```
for (( var = 0; var < ${#get_groups[*]}; var++ ));
do
  get_projectname_from_user_group=$(echo ${get_groups[$var]} | cut -d ' ' -f 4)
  create_project ${get_projectname_from_user_group}
done
```

When I go to the function "create_project()" and tried to display POST_ARGS:

```
echo ${POST_ARGS[@]}
```

I got positive result:

```
-d {"name": "IT", "versionRequest": {"versionName": "1.0", "phase": "PLANNING", "distribution": "INTERNAL"}} --header Content-Type: application/json
-d {"name": "IOSS", "versionRequest": {"versionName": "1.0", "phase": "PLANNING", "distribution": "INTERNAL"}} --header Content-Type: application/json
-d {"name": "IMGE", "versionRequest": {"versionName": "1.0", "phase": "PLANNING", "distribution": "INTERNAL"}} --header Content-Type: application/json
```

In the end of function "project_name" you can find post $path. When I went to the function "post()" and tried to display POST_ARGS there:

```
echo ${POST_ARGS[@]}
```

I got:

```
-d {"name": "IT", "versionRequest": {"versionName": "1.0", "phase": "PLANNING", "distribution": "INTERNAL"}} --header Content-Type: application/json
./rbac_mapping_to_bd.bash: line 54: cut: No such file or directory
-d {"name": "", "versionRequest": {"versionName": "1.0", "phase": "PLANNING", "distribution": "INTERNAL"}} --header Content-Type: application/json
./rbac_mapping_to_bd.bash: line 54: cut: No such file or directory
-d {"name": "", "versionRequest": {"versionName": "1.0", "phase": "PLANNING", "distribution": "INTERNAL"}} --header Content-Type: application/json
```

It means, that for the first line it works fine, but for the next 2 it doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: `get_groups=["..."]` does NOT create an array. `get_groups=("..." "..." ...)` creates an array.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I give it just for example, it's array, because I can get every element one by one, by typing echo ${get_groups[1]}

Comment: OK, I got you. It was just confusing.

Answer (score 1):

To get the fourth element within each element of `get_groups`, you can simply use a temporary array and split each of the elements of `get_groups` into the temporary array making any use of the fourth element you need. E.g.

```
get_groups=("ABC MM CC IT Test RW"
            "ABC GG CMN IOSS Test RW"
            "ABC WW IMG IMGE Test RW")

for i in "${get_groups[@]}"; do     ## loop over each element 
    tmp=( $(echo $i) )              ## split element into tmp array
    echo ${tmp[3]}                  ## output 4th element
done
```

(**note**: double-quoting IS required around `"${get_groups[@]}"` in the `for` loop declaration and *command substitution* passing `$i` to `echo` is used to ensure *word-splitting* occurs.)

**Example Use/Output**

Copying/pasting the above into a terminal would produce:

```
IT
IOSS
IMGE
```

Let me know if this is not what you need. You can pass the fourth element to any function you need rather than outputting it as done above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    for i in ${!get_groups[*]}; do 
        get_projectname_from_user_group=`echo "${get_groups[$i]}" | awk -F" " '{print $4}'`
        if ! [ -z "$get_projectname_from_user_group" ]; then
            create_project "$get_projectname_from_user_group"
        fi
    done
```